# Incompatible pointer when int and long are the same?

Tags: c, pointers, types, warnings, compiler-warnings

When compiling C for a platform where int and long are both 32 bits, and long long is 64 bit (like clang or gcc `-m32` or clang's wasm32-unknown-wasi target), I get errors about incompatible pointer types:

```
int32_t *i1 = NULL;
long *l1 = i1;
int64_t *i2 = NULL;
long *l2 = i2;
```

```
sizeof.c:13:11: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'long *' with an expression of type 'int32_t *' (aka 'int *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    long *l1 = i1;
          ^    ~~
sizeof.c:15:11: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'long *' with an expression of type 'int64_t *' (aka 'long long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    long *l2 = i2;
          ^    ~~
2 warnings generated.
```

I find it strange, that neither `int32_t` nor `int64_t` is compatible with `long`.
Why is there a warning if int and long are the same?

Comment: They're warnings, not errors.

Comment: The warnings are probably because the code is non-portable, since it depends on the types being the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C’s rules about what makes types compatible are partly about the “meaning” of the type, not just how big it is, what values it represents, or how it represents them. In these rules pointers to `int` and `long` are different and incompatible types even if they use the same number of bytes and encode addresses in the same way and point to `int` and `long` that use the same number of bytes and encode numbers in the same way.

The C standard may permit a C implementation to defined (by `typedef`) `int32_t` and `int64_t` to be `int`, `long`, or `long long`, as appropriate. In this case the corresponding types would be not just compatible but identical. However the standard also permits them to be defined as extended types, distinct from the basic integer types even if they function identically. As [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie-for-yellow-blockquotes) notes, your C implementation likely defines `int32_t` to be `int` and `int64_t` to be `long long`, and so neither is compatible with `long`.

The “meaning” of the type involves some things about what humans plan to use the type for and what it means to the compiler. `int` originally meant a size good with the target processor in some sense, but that has been weakened over time. Two structure types might be defined with identical elements, but one contains x-y coordinates for a two-dimensional graph and the other contains real-imaginary parts for complex numbers. Having these be separate and incompatible types helps programmers avoid some errors.

By and large, code such as `int32_t x; int *p = &x;` was written in error, and a warning is desirable to point that out. And the warning is no hindrance as it is easy to write code that functions as desired without getting the warning.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a lot. I didn't know that they are treated different even if they are the same size.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `long *` is compatible with neither `int32_t *` nor `int64_t *` if these types are defined this way on your platform:

```
typedef int int32_t;
typedef long long int int64_t;
```

The standard types `int`, `long` and `long long` are different even if they have the same size and/or representation.

There is nothing in the C Standard that mandates which of `int`, `long` and `long long` should be used for specified size integers, provided one of them matches its number of bits and two's complement representation requirements. `int32_t` could even be defined as a separate extended type with the appropriate ranking.

You must use the proper pointer types in your code and avoid assumptions on actual representation of the basic integer types.